# Hard to count subsets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, dynamic-programming, combinatorics-on-words

Suppose $\mathcal{B}=\{0,1\}^N$ is the set of binary sequences of length $N$. I am looking for examples of subsets $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{B}$ which are easy to describe, in the sense that all sequences in $\mathcal{A}$ have some common property easy to define, but which are very hard to count, i.e. calculating the size of $\mathcal{A}$ would require writing a complicated program, preferably more complicated than a dynamic programming algorithm. Is there any official list with examples of such sets ?

Comment: I think most sets you come up with work

Comment: Your question is too general. As subsets of this form encode any subset of $\{0, \dotsm, 2^n-1\}$ you can take a property very hard to check, for instance the set of natural numbers $k$ such that $2^k-1$ is a (Mersenne) prime.

Answer (score 1):

How about sets where consecutive blocks of ones have different size.

Comment: Thanks ! Can we somehow prove that this is difficult to count exactly ?